# CircleCI test failing due to the "hstore" Postgres extension not being installed

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, yaml, circleci

I'm trying to get a certain commit to pass the tests on CircleCI, but there are some differences with my local environment that I'm still trying to resolve. Here is the `./circleci/config.yml` file:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/lucy/lucy_web/
    docker:
      - image: python:3.6.0
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: postgresql://my_app:my_password@localhost/my_db?sslmode=disable
      - image: jannkleen/docker-postgres-gis-hstore
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: my_app
          POSTGRES_DB: my_db
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "lucy-web/requirements.txt" }}
      - run:
          name: Install Python deps in a venv
          command: |
            cd lucy-web
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - save_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "lucy-web/requirements.txt" }}
          paths:
            - "venv"
      - run:
          command: |
            cd lucy-web
            source venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py compilescss --verbosity 0
            python manage.py collectstatic --clear --no-input --verbosity 0
            python manage.py makemigrations --no-input --verbosity 0
            python manage.py migrate --no-input --verbosity 0
            python manage.py test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports/
          destination: tr1
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-reports/
```

The problem is that the tests error out due to the `hstore` type not existing:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "options" varchar(255)[] NOT NULL, "conditions" hstore NOT...
                                                             ^

Exited with code 1
```

On my local machine, I solved this by running `psql my_db` followed by `create extension hstore;`. Looking at the PostgreSQL image's source code (https://github.com/JannKleen/docker-postgres-gis-hstore), I believe it runs the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
POSTGRES="gosu postgres"

echo "******CREATING EXTENSIONS******"

${POSTGRES} psql -d postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template0';"
${POSTGRES} psql -d postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template1';"
${POSTGRES} psql -d template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;"
${POSTGRES} psql -d template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;"
${POSTGRES} psql -d template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;"

echo ""
echo "******DATABASE EXTENSIONS******"
```

As I understand it, if the extension is created in the `template1` database, it should apply the the `my_db` database too, right? (Cf. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and here's how I solved it.  My app is a node app but the basic idea should be the same.  I've trimmed out anything specific to my project apart from the Postgres setup.

```yaml
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/postgres:10.3-alpine
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER: root
          - POSTGRES_PASS: test
          - POSTGRES_DB: circle-test

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Postgres Client
          command: sudo apt install postgresql-client

      - run:
          name: Stash the PG Password
          command: echo "test" > .pgpass

      - run:
          name: Waiting for PostgreSQL to start
          command: |
            for i in `seq 1 10`;
            do
              nc -z localhost 5432 && echo Success && exit 0
              echo -n .
              sleep 2
            done
            echo Failed waiting for Postgres && exit 1

      - run:
          name: Enable hstore in Postgres
          command: psql -U root -d circle-test -h localhost -p 5432 -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;"
```